# Why do we need Tap operator in Rxjs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am new to Rxjs and I am watching one of the tutorials of David Acosta related to Rxjs operators.
In that, he was saying that when we don't need to touch the data of an observable we can use tap operator. 
So, the data inside the tap function won't be changed.

I wrote the below code

```
 const source = Observable.of("david");

    source.pipe(
      tap(x => x.toString().toUpperCase())
    ).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I got the output as `david`.
But I was wondering like

```
source.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

gives the same output `david`. Then why do we need the tap operator.
It was kind of mystery for me and I couldn't get proper resource for me that explains the `TAP` operator

Could any one explain me in detail about this and suggest me some good tutorials or documentation for Rxjs operators

Comment: Not specific to Rxjs, but usually *tap* is used as a debugging tool to examine the data at this point in the sequence of changes. You might be able to do mutate the data and continue but it's not generally a good idea. Different implementations of pipes/streams might have different rationale or in fact might disallow it altogether or allow it with no problems. Broadly, you don't want to do a transformation when tapping, as it could mess up some of the other operations.

Comment: Then what is the side effect of tapping. As you are saying `don't want to a transformation`.

Comment: Depends on the implementation. E.g., in Java example, the compiler might optimise away the `.tap` operation on streams. If you rely on it, then your code might randomly not work. In other places, it might mess up different optimisations. Or it might mess the parallelisation of the operations. The most generic answer is that operating on data is *supposed* to be done via [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) - that simplifies the math that goes into optimising the operations *and* allows for trivial multi-threading, since you change state.

Comment: If you wanted to for example save your data in localStorage, but not transform your data in observable pipeline, you could use `tap(x => localStorage.setItem('Name', x))`. It would just cause some sideeffect, but wouldn't have any impact on your observable pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Tap operator is normally used for 2 use cases:

1- **Store/watch** the value of the observable stream:

```
const source = Observable.of("david");

let name;

source.pipe(
   tap(x => name = x)
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

console.log('variable name: ', name);
```

2- Perform some **side effect** that you want to be executed in some place on the pipeline (not on subscribe):

```
clickStream$.pipe(
   tap((event) => {
       event.stopPropagation();
       event.preventDefault();
   }),
   debounce(300),
   map((event) => event.key)
).subscribe((key) => console.log('key debounced: ', key))
```

**Note**: Be careful using tap operator for performing side effects in your code. Some are justified and correct, but others could be solved just performing your side effect on .subscribe callback.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Tap isn't exactly the same as adding a subscription.  For example, if you have a client to an HTTP server you might have something that looks like...

```
function getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
  return makeSomeExpensiveHttpCall()
    .map(rsp => doSomeExpensiveParsing(rsp))
    .tap(items => console.log(`Received ${items.length} items`));    
}
```

...which at first glance is equivalent to...

```
function getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
  const result = return makeSomeExpensiveHttpCall()
    .map(rsp => doSomeExpensiveParsing(rsp));
  result.subscribe(items => {
    console.log(`Received ${items.length} items`);
  });
  return result;
}
```

However, the way it is currently written, every time you call `subscribe` it is going to execute `makeSomeExpensiveHttpCall` and `doSomeExpensiveParsing`.  So in the second example you are likely going to end up calling those functions twice instead of once.  You will send two identical HTTP requests to the server.  We definitely want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use `tap` when you want to do something always when you get a value, but you don't want to get all the values ​​ as a result (you just need a specific type) and hence you filter your stream.
For example your building an arryay with numbers only divisible by 2 and you don't need other numbers.

But also, using `tap` is a matter of a clean code in a lot of times.

Simple code a reference:

```
myObservable$ = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(1);
    observer.next(2);
    observer.next(3);
    observer.next(4);
    observer.next(5);
    observer.next(6);
    observer.complete();
});


this.myObservable$
  .pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('got Value!')),
    filter(value => (value % 2) === 0),
  )
  .subscribe(value => {
    console.log('filtered: ', value);
    this.mySpecificArray.push(value);
   });
```